# Numpy Masked Array changes zeros to a huge number when uploaded in another script

Tags: python, numpy, boolean, mask

I have a script where I create masks on a gridded array for certain distances from the coastline and save them to a netcdf file. I have a grid file with latitude, longitude and a land mask (netcdf files). My script (simplified here) does the following:

```
from netCDF4 import Dataset

grd = Dataset('gridfile', 'r')
mask_rho = grd.variables['mask_rho'][:]
lat = grd.variables['lat'][:]

full_region = np.copy(mask_rho) #copy land mask from grid file

full_region[lat<5] = 0. #masks latitudes above and below region of interest
full_region[lat>35] = 0.

mask_full = np.ma.masked_where(full_region==0., full_region) #numpy mask

filename = directory+'mask.nc'
ncfile = Dataset(filename, 'w', format='NETCDF4')
ncfile.createDimension('lat', lat)
ncfile.createDimension('lon',lon)
Dims = ('lat,'lon')

data = ncfile.createVariable('mask_full','f4',Dims)
data[:] = mask_full

ncfile.close()
```

However, when I open the netcdf file i created in another script, the data seems to come in three forms:

1. 'masked data' (masked out values are blank, values within the mask are 1)
2. 'data' (values within the mask are 1, and masked out values are some huge number, 996920996838.....)
3. and 'mask', which is a true/false boolean.

Why is the 'data' part giving me such a huge number? And why are there three data types?